# Fortran g77 compiler can't recognize o.f or comment "c"

Tags: file, comments, fortran

I was using Fortran g77 and experienced this problem:

```
c this program calculates runoff and sediment
  1 2
 Unrecognized statement name at (1) and invalid form for assignment or statement-function definition at (2)
```

Also, the compiler can recognized only `.for` file extension, not `.f`.

Does anyone know, where is the problem? I downloaded it from http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~roumani/fortran/ftn.htm.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is not recognizing that statement as a comment.  As a comment it should ignore the line but it is trying parse it.  Are you sure that the "C" is in the first column?

Why are you using g77?  It hasn't been supported for years.   gfortran is the current GNU Fortran compiler.   It can compile FORTRAN 77, Fortran 90, 95 and portions of 2003 and 2008.

EDIT:  Perhaps its wants an upper-case "C".

Comment: I tried. Can you please help downloading gfortran77 or whatever the version? I am a  beginner and do not have much idea.

Comment: For the current compiler gfortran, see http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinaries.   If you wish to use it for fixed-layout source code (FORTRAN 77 style), use options "-ffixed-form  -ffixed-line-length-none".

Answer (score 1):

The page you have linked to states that the `f2exe` wrapper passes `-ffree-form` to the compiler:

> Compilation Command
>
> The above `f2exe` command is just a batch file that invokes `g77`, the "real" compilation command. The command:
> `g77 -ffree-form prog.for -oprog.exe`
> directs the compiler to compile the file `prog.for` and stores the output in the file `prog.exe`. The `-ffree-form` switch indicates free-form style (remove it if you are using the old style).

In free-form Fortran the only allowed comment format is that of a line starting with `!`. As a matter of fact, this is also written on the same page directly under the above text:

> Comments
>
> In free-form style, use `!` for both full-line and in-line comments. In the old style, use a "C" in column-1.

If you are not using the provided `f2exe` wrapper, don't pass `-ffree-form` option when compiling fixed-form FORTRAN 77 code.

Comment: where I can find "g77 -ffree-form prog.for -oprog.exe" and how to remove "-ffree-form" part?

Comment: @user1702268, it's all written on the web page that you have linked to.

Comment: I am new to Fortran. Can you please help me doing this?

Comment: I would suggest that you start by downloading a more modern compiler suite, e.g. [gfortran](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinaries). The [TDM-GCC](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/) build looks promising. `gfortran` parses the source code as fixed-form if it has `.f` extension or if `-ffixed-form` option is provided.

Comment: @LLiev: Can you please tell me where I can find the f77 compiler for free download? Also, is there any other compiler that can compile codes written in f77? Thank you.

Comment: @Atikur, I have given you **two** links to GCC. There is a modern Fortran compiler, called `gfortran`, included in the GCC family and most binary packages have it. It is able to compile both old fixed-format FORTRAN 77 code and modern free-format Fortran 90+ code.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you want to stick with this compiler.

As noted above, *the problems you have come from using the F2EXE batch file*, which is not very useful: first it automatically adds ".for" to the file name, so you can't compile ".f" files, and it assumes free-form syntax, which is unusual when programming in Fortran 77 (and if you want Fortran 90, find another compiler, other answers give you links).

---

Now, suppose you have written a program myprogram.f, and you are in a Windows command line, in the same directory where the program resides (use "cd C:\mydirectory" for example, to change)

You will compile with

```
g77 myprogram.f
```

If you use SLATEC, you use

```
g77 myprogram.f -lslatec
```

If you want to specify a name for your .exe file (default is a.exe), you write

```
g77 myprogram.f -o myprogram.exe
```

There are other useful options

```
g77 -O2 myprogram.f     to optimize (within g77 2.95 limitations)
g77 -Wall myprogram.f   to enable all compiler warnings, very useful
                          to find errors in your code
g77 -c myprogram.f      to only compile (you get a .o file), this is
                          useful to compile functions and subroutines, to
                          later build a static library (.a file), like
                          libslatec.a which is given with the compiler
```

And to build a library, using ar.exe:

```
ar cru mylib.a myfunc1.o myfnuc2.o ...
```

Then you can use is with

```
g77 myprogram.f mylib.a
```

G77 runs in command line under Windows. You write programs in a text editor.
Notepad++ is fairly good and its free. See http://notepad-plus-plus.org/

If you have problems with compilation, maybe it comes from environment variables, so here are some precisions. You have to tell Windows where to find the G77 compiler (g77.exe).

You can follow instructions on the site where you downloaded it to change Windows' environment variables PATH and LIBRARY_PATH. It needs you install the compiler in the C:\F directory : that is, you will have C:\F\G77\bin, etc.

Slight modification to the instructions on that page :

- You should set **PATH** to **C:\F\G77\bin**
- And **LIBRARY_PATH** to **C:\F\G77\lib;C:\F\SLATEC\lib**

This modification to LIBRARY_PATH allows you to compile with SLATEC simply with "-lslatec" as above.

---

A note about the compiler. It's G77, also know as *GNU Fortran 77*. An old compiler, integrated with the well known GCC suite until GCC 3.4.6 (we are at GCC 4.7.2 now). And the compiler you downloaded is for version GCC 2.95.

It's a good Fortran 77 compiler, but it's not very well optimized, and of course, you don't get any support for new processor features such as Intel SSE.

Modern Fortran compilers can still understand most if not all of Fortran 77, plus all the newer features of Fortran 90 and newer standards, which are extremely useful.

It may also be interesting to know there is another place to download the same compiler (eccept there is no SLATEC), just in case the page gets destroyed :
http://www.mbr-pwrc.usgs.gov/software/g77.html

Comment: I have some source codes in fortran f77 and want to modify for my research. I was using g77 compiler but that can't compile the codes. Can you please tell me where I can find the f77 compiler for free download? Also, is there any compiler that can compile codes written in f77? Thank you.

Comment: If you are on Windows, you can try gfortran (Fortran 77 and Fortran 90): [link](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinaries) or OpenWatcom (Fortran 77 only, plus some extensions): [link](ftp://ftp.openwatcom.org/). If you are on Linux with a x86 procesor (or x86-64), there are more choices: Sun Studio, Open64, Pathscale Ekopath, Intel Fortran, and of course gfortran and openwatcom. Some of the preceding are commercial, but free for personnal use. There is also g77, but you don't want it (just in case, there are binaries for windows, and it's still possible to compile gcc-3.4.6 on Linux).